# Magento2 How to translate City names in the Arabic language

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, plugin

How to translate City names in the Arabic language.
here is the screenshot.
https://i.imgur.com/2UVdzrJ.png
I can not translate city names on my account page.

Answer (score 0):

If your **locale** is set to **Arabic(Saudi Arabia)** from admin panel you can do following

1. In custom module, you need to create i18n folder and if you're using the above locale then you need to create **ar_SA.csv** file inside this folder

(if you are using another locale then you need to find the name of the csv, you can easily find it online)

2. In custom theme,

<parent_theme_dir> / i18n / (repeated on all child themes)

<current_theme_dir> / i18n / (works on current theme only)

**Now, for the content of csv file you need to enter the word you need to translate in your language, like**

"India","الهند"

**In your case**

"hitteen","حطين"

"Abdaly","العبدلي"

**Note:** Make sure you enter capital and small letter perfectly, like the word render **india** and you want to translate this and you enter **India** it will not work

what I am trying to say is, enter the word as they render in front like

- render **india**, then in csv "india","الهند"
- render **India**, then in csv "India","الهند"

You can translate whole sentence also, like

"your sentence in whatever rendering language","your sentence in your locale language"

but, same rule for the capital and small letters

Hope this will help you